# How to set Matlab shortcuts in Ubuntu?

Tags: shortcuts, matlab

I am not able to use the shortcuts which are available in matlab (in Windows) in Ubuntu. I am not so good with softwares and looking for an easy solution. Could somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using recent versions of Matlab, go for this:
Home -> preferences -> Keyboard -> shortcuts

In shortcuts, click on the shortcut you want to change. Then it will be displayed under: 'Shortcuts for '
Click on it once and then press the shortcut combination you want. Then click on apply. Make sure there is no conflict in which care it will show a red cross. In such a case, you will need to change the conflicting shortcut first.